# Typescript initialize two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have the following class:

```
export class ReservationInfo {
    public person: Person;
    public reservation: Reservation;

    constructor(person: Person, reservation: Reservation) {
        this.person = person;
        this.reservation = reservation;
    }

}
```

This class contains two custom classes.

```
export class Person {
    public id: number;
    public personal_no: number;
    public first_name: string;
    public last_name: string;
    public email: string;
    public gender: string;
    public address: string;
    public birthdate: Date;
    public phone: string;
}
export class Reservation {
    public id: number;
    public create_date: Date;
    public update_date: Date;
    public personal_no: number;
    public status_id: string;
    public payment_status_id: string;
    public payment_type: string;
    public comment: string;
    public res_type: string;
    public reservationDetail: Array<ReservationDetail>;
}
```

Reservation class contains ReservationDetail class which's have array list type of ReservationPerson.

```
export class ReservationDetail {
    public id: number;
    public reservation_id: number;
    public create_date: Date;
    public update_date: Date;
    public room_id: number;
    public status_id: string;
    public start_date: Date;
    public end_date: Date;
    public payment_type: string;
    public adult: string;
    public child: string;
    public additional_bed: string;
    public payment_status: string;
    public category_id: number;
    public category_name: string;
    public extra_person: string;
    public reservationPerson: Array<ReservationPerson>;
    public reservationService: Array<ReservationServices>;
   constructor(id: number, reservation_id: number, create_date: Date, update_date: Date, status_id: string, room_id: number, start_date: Date, end_date: Date, category_id: number,
        reservationPerson: Array<ReservationPerson>, reservationService: Array<ReservationServices>) {
        this.id = id;
        this.reservation_id = reservation_id;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.update_date = update_date;
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.room_id = room_id;
        this.start_date = start_date;
        this.end_date = end_date;
        this.category_id = category_id;
        this.reservationPerson = reservationPerson;
        this.reservationService = reservationService;
    }
}
```

This is my ReservationPerson class with it's constuctor.

```
export class ReservationPerson {
    public reservation_id: number;
    public person_id: string;
    public first_name: string;
    public last_name: string;

    constructor(person_id: string, first_name: string, last_name: string) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
}
```

I have a initialisation promlem.

when i try to create ReservationIfo class instance using the following code,reservationPerson property null.

```
new ReservationInfo(new Person(null, null, '', '', '', '', '', new Date(), ''), new Reservation(null, null, null, null, null, [
      new ReservationDetail(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, [new ReservationPerson('a', 'b', 'c')], [new ReservationServices(null, 'a', 'b', 'v', 'dv')])
    ]));
```

When i try the following code second element reservationPerson is not null.

```
new ReservationInfo(new Person(null, null, '', '', '', '', '', new Date(), ''), new Reservation(null, null, null, null, null, [
      new ReservationDetail(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, [new ReservationPerson('a', 'b', 'c')], [new ReservationServices(null, 'a', 'b', 'v', 'dv')]),
      new ReservationDetail(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, [new ReservationPerson('a', 'b', 'c')], [new ReservationServices(null, 'a', 'b', 'v', 'dv')])
    ]));
```

I think i have 0 index element problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameters to your classes to initialize it the way you are initializing.

To create a `Person` object using the syntax you are using `new Person(null, null, '', '', '', '', '', new Date(), '')` add the properties as parameter properties:

```
export class Person {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public personal_no: number,
        public first_name: string,
        public last_name: string,
        public email: string,
        public gender: string,
        public address: string,
        public birthdate: Date,
        public phone: string
    ) { }
}
```

See [documentation on parameter properties.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties)

Comment: ReservationDetail  class have properties reservationPerson and reservationService, also have constructor thats have this properties. Whole initialisation is this new ReservationInfo(new Person(..), new Reservation(..., [
      new ReservationDetail(.., [new ReservationPerson('a', 'b', 'c')], [new ReservationServices(null, 'a', 'b', 'v', 'dv')]),
      new ReservationDetail(..., [new ReservationPerson('a', 'b', 'c')], [new ReservationServices(null, 'a', 'b', 'v', 'dv')])
    ])); Here first ReservationDetail does not have ReservationPerson but seconds have when i print.